# Forced-air heater for old floor registers

Tags: hvac, heating, ducts, forced-air

I have an older home which used to be centrally heated by a furnace in the crawlspace, but has since been retrofitted with forced-air wall heaters: [image: forced-air wall heater] Some of the wall heaters are in inconvenient locations (like under windows where I'd like to add drapery), so I'm looking at options to replace them. I could replace the furnace, but the retrofit was probably done a decade or two ago and I don't know the condition of the ducts. There are still floor registers remaining from the central heating, and these seem like ideal locations for heating since the vents and ducts are already there.

Are there any forced-air heaters available which can be installed in unused floor registers? Something like the [toe-kick heaters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001MXNGG4) I've seen for installation under kitchen and bathroom cabinets.

Comment: When you say toe kick are you talking about baseboard heaters? Depending on the age of the home the old duct work may be rusted out the only way to know would be to inspect the trunk lines, my guess they were in bad shape and it was cheaper to put in the wall heaters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called floor drop-in heaters.  Qmark makes one. And another company called Dimplex makes one. Find them on-line. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Toe kick heaters such as the slant fin sidekick are fan assist hydronic heaters as far as I know. Any heaters that fit in the register space that I've seen were electric, and that is expense to run and won't deliver much heat. They do exist so depending on your climate they may work for you. Dimplex makes one but I think it requires some installation. I've seen some that simply plug in. I just don't know who makes them.